# Craft 3 CMS How to get all Channel Names/Titles

Tags: templating, craft3, craft-features, craft-pro, twigextension

I am trying to retrieve all Channel sections' names/titles.
This snippet contains the troublesome part.

```
{% set allSections = craft.entries.all() %}
    {% for section in allSections %}
        {% if section.getType() == "channel" %}
            {% set navBarLinks = navBarLinks|merge([section.title]) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

allSections contains all entries (I know I am looking for sections but I don't know how to loop all sections. craft.sections returns null, since it's deprecated from Craft 2). ex:

I can see the entry inside a channel 'webshop/overview'. But I want to get only the name of the channel ('webshop' in this case).
Also I have 2 other channels without any entries inside them.

navBarLinks currently returns null. I want it to contain the names/titles of the Channel sections regardless if they contain entries inside them.

P.S. I am doing all this so I can have a dynamic navigation bar(similar to breadcrumbs but not exactly). I know Structure will make my life a lot easier but it doesn't quite fit my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of solved my problem:

```
{% for section in craft.app.sections.allSections %}
    {% if section.type == 'channel' %}
        {% set navBarLinks = navBarLinks|merge([section]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: if it solved your problem, you can accept your post as an answer.

Comment: I can do that in 2 days apparently. Thanks!